# Can't find the ROI creation dock in SCP Toolbar

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I'm following the tutorial http://semiautomaticclassificationmanual-v4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Tutorials.html using QGIS 2.16.3 on Ubuntu 16.04. In the section 3.1.4, a shapefile is created using ROI Creation Docker. But I can't locate this in my SCP Toolbar.

[image]

The closest I got was the ROI Creation section located under Classification Dock, but even it doesn't allow you to add shapefiles.

Is this because I'm using an incompatible Plugin version or has this capability been replaced by some other feature?